# How to create space between block and paragraph

Tags: beamer, margins, block, beamer-metropolis

I am preparing a Latex Beamer presentation using the metropolis theme. The output looks good except one problem; in the `definition` block, there is no space between the text and the border of the block, and it doesn't look very aesthetic. Here is the code I wrote and the output:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=54, 10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\setbeamertemplate{frame numbering}[fraction]
\useoutertheme{metropolis}
\useinnertheme{metropolis}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usecolortheme{spruce}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e,mathtools,tikz}
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{}{\justifying}

\justifying

\title{Probabilité}
\subtitle{Analyse Combinatoire}
\author{}
\date[]{}
\institute[]{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\metroset{block=fill}
\begin{frame}{Analyse Combinatoire}
    L'analyse combinatoire est l’étude des ensembles finis du point de vue du nombre de leurs éléments. Elle porte sur le dénombrement de configurations d’objets satisfaisant des conditions données. La combinatoire sert d’outil dans plusieurs problèmes élémentaires en théorie des probabilités.
    \begin{definition}[Le principe de multiplication]
        permet de compter le nombre de résultats d’expériences qui peuvent se décomposer en une succession de sous-expériences.
        Si une expérience est la succession de $m$ sous-expériences. Si la $i$ ème expérience a $n_i$ résultats possibles pour $i = 1,\dots, n$, alors le nombre total de résultats possibles de l’expérience globale est:
    \[n=\prod_{i=1}^{m}n_{i}=n_{1}\times n_{2}\times\dots\times n_{m}\]
    \end{definition}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How do I create some space between the paragraph and the block border? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you want to indent the text wrt to the gray area (and wrt to the text above) OR do you want to expand the gray area left and right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## `moloch` theme

You can avoid the problem by using the `moloch` theme, a more up-to-date fork of the `metropolis` theme:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=54, 10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme
\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[totalframenumber]
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usecolortheme{spruce}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e,mathtools,tikz}
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{}{\justifying}

\setbeamercolor{block title}{%
  use=normal text,
  fg=normal text.fg,
  bg=normal text.bg!80!fg
}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{
  use={block title, normal text},
  bg=block title.bg!50!normal text.bg
}

\justifying

\title{Probabilité}
\subtitle{Analyse Combinatoire}
\author{}
\date[]{}
\institute[]{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Analyse Combinatoire}
    L'analyse combinatoire est l’étude des ensembles finis du point de vue du nombre de leurs éléments. Elle porte sur le dénombrement de configurations d’objets satisfaisant des conditions données. La combinatoire sert d’outil dans plusieurs problèmes élémentaires en théorie des probabilités.
    \begin{definition}[Le principe de multiplication]
        permet de compter le nombre de résultats d’expériences qui 
    \end{definition}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Default beamer blocks

You can revert back to normal beamer blocks by setting the `begin block` and `end block` templates:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=54, 10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\setbeamertemplate{frame numbering}[fraction]
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usecolortheme{spruce}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e,mathtools,tikz}
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{}{\justifying}

\metroset{block=fill}
\setbeamertemplate{block begin}[default]
\setbeamertemplate{block end}[default]

\justifying

\title{Probabilité}
\subtitle{Analyse Combinatoire}
\author{}
\date[]{}
\institute[]{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{frame}{Analyse Combinatoire}
    L'analyse combinatoire est l’étude des ensembles finis du point de vue du nombre de leurs éléments. Elle porte sur le dénombrement de configurations d’objets satisfaisant des conditions données. La combinatoire sert d’outil dans plusieurs problèmes élémentaires en théorie des probabilités.
    \begin{definition}[Le principe de multiplication]
        permet de compter le nombre de résultats d’expériences qui peuvent se décomposer en une succession de sous-expériences.
        Si une expérience est la succession de $m$ sous-expériences. Si la $i$ ème expérience a $n_i$ résultats possibles pour $i = 1,\dots, n$, alors le nombre total de résultats possibles de l’expérience globale est:
    \[n=\prod_{i=1}^{m}n_{i}=n_{1}\times n_{2}\times\dots\times n_{m}\]
    \end{definition}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

## `tcolorbox` inner theme

If you need more control of the spacing, you could load the `tcolorbox` inner theme. It will replace the default blocks with tcolorboxes, which are designed to replicate the look and feel of normal beamer blocks. You can use the various tcolorbox options to further adjust the spacing to your liking:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=54, 10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme
\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[totalframenumber]
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usecolortheme{spruce}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e,mathtools,tikz}
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{}{\justifying}

\setbeamercolor{block title}{%
  use=normal text,
  fg=normal text.fg,
  bg=normal text.bg!80!fg
}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{
  use={block title, normal text},
  bg=block title.bg!50!normal text.bg
}

\useinnertheme{tcolorbox}

\justifying

\title{Probabilité}
\subtitle{Analyse Combinatoire}
\author{}
\date[]{}
\institute[]{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Analyse Combinatoire}
    L'analyse combinatoire est l’étude des ensembles finis du point de vue du nombre de leurs éléments. Elle porte sur le dénombrement de configurations d’objets satisfaisant des conditions données. La combinatoire sert d’outil dans plusieurs problèmes élémentaires en théorie des probabilités.
    \begin{definition}[Le principe de multiplication]
        permet de compter le nombre de résultats d’expériences qui 
    \end{definition}
    
    \tcbset{boxsep=0.2cm}
    \begin{definition}[Le principe de multiplication]
        permet de compter le nombre de résultats d’expériences qui 
    \end{definition}    
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: @SaïdMaanan You're welcome! Have fun with beamer!